# Why (&) sign is not showing in android default messaging app?

Tags: javascript, android, html, url, sms

I am using `sms` method in html to send my message (`Hello & Welcome`) through android default messaging app.

Here is my code:

```
    <a href="sms:001234567890?body=Hello%20%26%20Welcome">
        <button>
            Say Hello,
        </button>
    </a>
```

I have expect `Hello & Welcome`

[image: My Expectation]

But android default messaging app is only showing `Hello` not `& Welcome` (full message body)

[image: Result]

I have also tried:

`%26`
`&`
`&amp;`
`&#38;`
`&#x26;`

But it's still not showing.

Comment: You might try percent-encoding the percent sign on the encoded ampersand; i.e., `body=Hello%20%2526%20Welcome`, specifically `%2526` in there. Depending on exactly how the particular SMS app reads and decodes the body, it might end up with `&` or `%26` in the message, but since you're using it in a URL, either should be OK, I would think.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you `%2526` works thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have discovered a bug!
Note the differences here (`&`, `%`):

- IOS:

  `<a href="sms:1234&body=hi">Send an SMS</a>`
- Android:

  `<a href="sms:1234?body=Test">Send an SMS</a>`

You can combine these to support both like so:

```
 <a href="sms:0427618944?&body=Blah">Send a SMS message</a>
```

Now... This has been quite a pain. I've even been able to crash Android Messenger... I am able to find little to no documentation about SMS links.

Specifically there is problems with `&`. The below i am inserting an exclamation mark and it is working fine.

```
 <a href="sms:0427618944?&body=Hello%20%21%20Welcome">Send a SMS message</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the solution of my problem because I have to send a link through sms that contains `&` sign in it, if i replace that link's `&` sign with `!` sign then it will become invalid so that i cannot change `&` sign. but if i send the same message using `android send intent` from an android application then it shows `&` sign.

Comment: @AndroidExpert Yeah mate I know, the problem is that there isn't currently a solution to the problem because it seems to be broken when inserting & symbols. The solution I have provided today is to say that there isn't a way to do it (at the moment)

Comment: Is there anyway that i can send my message from html using `android send intent` instead of `sms` method or is there any alternative for `sms`?

Comment: @AndroidExpert Is there a reason why the user needs to send the SMS? If it doesn't have to originate from the user you could use a service like Twillo

Comment: @AndroidExpert are you able to mark this as the current solution?

Answer (score 5):

**Try this**

```
    <a href="sms:001234567890?body=Hello+%26+Welcome">
```

[Refer this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: Thanks, but it's still showing `'Hello '` not full message.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method for encode when sending message and decode to show by given methods.

```
private String encodeMessage(String message) {
 message = message.replaceAll("&", ":and:");
 message = message.replaceAll("\\+", ":plus:");
 return StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(message);
}

private String decodeMessage(String message) {
 message = message.replaceAll(":and:", "&");
 message = message.replaceAll(":plus:", "+");
 return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(message);
}
```

Comment: Normally Emoji and special character not supported in messaging app, as you mentioned you are working on messaging app , so when sending message encode your body part then send, and when you want to show recieved message just use decode method by passing that encoded string .Only you have to add " implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4" in your build.gradle.

Comment: Sorry, I am not working on messaging app I am working in html where I have a button that uses `sms` method to write my message in any default messaging app on android and my problem is if my message contains `&` sign it won't show in android default messaging app.